# Bash: redirect to file, always create new

Tags: bash, io-redirection, symlink

In bash, a command link

```
echo test > actual.txt
```

will replace the contents of the file called `actual.txt` with "test", and create the file if it doesn't exist. However, if the file does exist, bash will just open it, truncate it, and write the new contents into the file.

Specifically, the redirect command fails in this scenario:

```
ln -s /some/illegal/path link.txt
echo test > link.txt
```

Bash 4.4.12 gives me the confusing error message `link.txt: No such file or directory`.

One way to avoid this is to make sure to delete the file before running the redirected command.

```
rm link.txt && echo test > link.txt
```

I was wondering, though, if there was some tweak of bash options or the redirect operator which will prevent this failure mode. Any ideas?

Comment: What if `link.txt` is a link to `/dir/file` where `/dir` is a file of type directory to which you have  write and search permission, but `/dir/file` doesn't exist (and the redirection would create it without an error message)? What about if `/dir/file` exists but is not a regular file (device, fifo, directory...), or you don't have write permission to it or search permission to `/dir`?

Comment: The shell option `set -C` may be of interest to folks poking around here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to write to a dead symbolic link is equivalent to trying to write to a path that does not exist.  There is no way to "tweak" the output redirection to create the path (including intermediate directories) in `bash`, and there are no shell options in `bash` that makes this automatic.

If the intermediate path exists, but the end point of the link does not, then it will be created by the redirection.

You may do something like

```
if [ -h file ] && [ ! -f file ]; then
    rm file
fi
```

to test whether "file" is a symbolic link (`-h`) and whether it refers to a regular file that exists (`-f`).  If it is a symbolic link but does not refer to a file, then you delete it.

Comment: The point of my question was that I'm not trying to write **to** anything. I want to create a new file called `link.txt`, and there happens to be a symbolic link in the same location.

To put this in the form of a question: why bother with the testing if I'm going to overwrite the file on the next line? I can just do `rm -f` and it will have the same effect.

Comment: @itsadok Ah. Yes. Just doing `rm -f filename` before writing to it with the redirection would also solve your issue. But it also depends on whether you'd like to it to be in the current directory or in the directory where the end point of the symbolic link is located.

Comment: You could still lack the permissions to `rm` the file or to write to it.  As in many cases, you cannot prepare for everything.  You need to assess which cases you really expect (if even as rare occasions) and therefore handle, which cases you consider so unlikely that you purposefully do not handle them, and accept that there will be a certain amount of cases you do *not* consider and thus cannot handle.